# How to convert multiple words in single line separated by comma in list of multiple lines

Tags: linux

I have below text in file txt file as in below format

```
["Dell Inc.", "192.168.101.134", "44:a8:42:27:c7:ba", "PowerEdge R630", "6P84N62", "8", "Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2623 v3 @ 3.00GHz", "32059.66", "172.16.100.21"]
```

but i need  this as below format how do i format in linux

```
Dell Inc. 
192.168.101.134
44:a8:42:27:c7:ba
PowerEdge R630 
6P84N62
8 
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2623 v3 @ 3.00GHz
32059.66
172.16.100.21
```

Comment: context? bash, c++, python, js ...?

Comment: using may be sed or awk if possible

Comment: assuming there're no embedded commas in the quoted fields: ```echo '["Dell Inc.", "192.168.101.134", "44:a8:42:27:c7:ba"]' | tr ',' '\n' | sed 's/[][]//'```

Comment: it works..thanks and below shared commands work but there double quote in the out put..i have just added   sed 's/"//g' to remove the double quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "your string" |tr \[ ' '|tr \] ' '|tr , \\n|awk '{$1=$1};1'
```

Explanation

- `echo "your string"` prints your string, then piped to the next `tr`
- `tr \[ ' '` substitutes [ with an empty space
- `tr \] ' '` substitutes ] with an empty space
- `tr , \\n` substitutes the comma with a newline
- `awk '{$1=$1};1'` (taken from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/205854)) trims spaces

Answer (score 0):

this command was giving the output with double quote. and to remove the double quote i have just added | tr [ ' '|tr ] ' '|tr , \n|awk '{$1=$1};1' | sed 's/"//g'

Thanks for the quick help..